# DHCP server causes slow docker-compose operations

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dhcp

[Updated as I have found **what** is causing the problem; now I need to know **why**.]

When I use a custom DHCP server on my network (a Raspberry Pi running [Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net)) Docker projects on my system take up to two minutes to start. With networking on my computer turned off, or using the DHCP server on my cable router, they take just a few seconds.

Here's a log with `docker-compose --verbose up`: https://dpaste.de/hcxP. It takes about 1m25s to get to line 150, and about another 30 to get to line 771. Does that log reveal anything useful?

The delays occur after each:

```
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container
```

and

```
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers
```

command.

In the later section, the final ~30 seconds or so,

```
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set([<Service: web>])
```

and

```
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set([])
```

repeat hundreds of times.

I'm on macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) and Docker:

- Engine: 17.12.0-ce
- Compose: 1.18.0
- Machine: 0.13.0

Once started, the application seems to run normally, but takes 25+ seconds to stop (and again, with networking on my computer turned off, or using the DHCP server on my cable router, it's almost instantaneous).

The slow-down is clearly triggered by the Pi-hole DHCP server, which in every other respect works perfectly well. The slow-down also occurs when filtering is *disabled* on the Pi-hole.

Any suggestions **why** the DHCP server might be responsible?

Comment: hey Daniele, did you manage to figure out a solution? I believe I have the same problem, docker-compose hangs for a while right after looking into the Dockerfile. can you re-upload the log? it's not available on dpaste anymore